# Qt delaying processing of mousePressEvent

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom button that can be right clicked in addition to left clicking. It works like this:

```
private slots:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
        if(e->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
                std::cout << "kek2";
                emit rightClicked();
        }
        QPushButton::mousePressEvent(e);
    }
```

For some weird reason left click works fine, and right clicks are not processed (judging by lack of kek2 outputs) until I do a left click, upon which all right clicks are processed at once. Why?

Comment: QPushButton is Qt default button that ignores right clicks. My button is a descendant of it. There won't be any loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at it and implemented an equivalent Button and changed your code to this:

```
void QRightClickButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(e->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
                    std::cout << "kek2" << std::endl; //the << std::endl; //made it work good again
                    emit rightClicked();
    } else if(e->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
     //this else if block is just a fast implementation of the leftclick
                    std::cout << "kek3" << std::endl;
                    QPushButton::mousePressEvent(e);
    }


}
```

Try it yourself both log messages ("kek2" as well as "kek3") appear instantly.
Without the `<< std::endl;` it is still buggy!

EDIT: I decided to add 2 more ways to do it!

2. You can also use it without `std::endl;`

   `std::cout << message; //prints message`

   `std::cout.flush(); //flushes the output so it will be visible as well`

For example you can create your own class or your own function.

3. Use `qDebug()`. qDebug automatically flushes the stream so you don't have to write extra code as well as it belongs to Qt self. That means you're not going to mix 2 libraries.

Use it that way:

```
qDebug() << message;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `qDebug()` since it ensures that the output is immediately flushed. `std::cout` doesn't have to. E.g. `qDebug() << "kek2"`. When using Qt, don't use `std::cout` for debug output, it's not worth it.
2. `mousePressEvent` is **not** a slot.